# Subprocess unrecognized arguments but command works in terminal

Tags: python, subprocess

I run the DeepSpeech command for wav to text and want to save the result into a text file like so:

```
deepspeech --model path/to/model --audio path/to/audio >> path/to/result.txt
```

It works in the terminal but if I try to run it as a subprocess in Python like that:

```
subprocess.run(["deepspeech", "--model", "path/to/model", "--audio", "path/to/audio", ">>", "path/to/result.txt"])
```

I get this:

```
usage: deepspeech [-h] --model MODEL [--lm [LM]] [--trie [TRIE]] --audio AUDIO
              [--beam_width BEAM_WIDTH] [--lm_alpha LM_ALPHA]
              [--lm_beta LM_BETA] [--version] [--extended] [--json]
deepspeech: error: unrecognized arguments: >> path/to/result.txt
```

Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do:

```py
with open("path/to/result.txt", mode="wb" as fd:
    subprocess.run(["deepspeech", "--model", "path/to/model", "--audio", "path/to/audio"], stdout=fd)
```

Or capture the output.

Read the documentation of [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Comment: Did it exactly like that, worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE : I was trying to run this command `with open("C:/Users/hp/Documents/result.txt", mode="wb") as fd:
    subprocess.run(["deepspeech", "--model", "--model C:/deepspeechwk/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/output_graph.pb --lm C:/deepspeechwk/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/lm.binary --trie C:/deepspeechwk/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/trie", "--audio", "C:/deepspeechwk/audio/8455-210777-0068.wav"], stdout=fd)` but the file which is generated is blank but the same is working when i run from terminal Can you please let me know what's the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
>> path/to/result.txt
```

This is not an argument to `deepspeech`. This is a shell feature called "output redirection". `deepspeech` obviously does not understand that.

To get the same behaviour in `subprocess` you can use the `stdout` option:

```
subprocess.run(["deepspeech", "--model", "path/to/model", "--audio", "path/to/audio"] , stdout=open("path/to/result.txt", 'a')])
```

For more info see the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) class

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None. PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created. DEVNULL indicates that the special file os.devnull will be used. With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent. Additionally, stderr can be STDOUT, which indicates that the stderr data from the applications should be captured into the same file handle as for stdout.

Comment: Don't forget to close the file… ;-)

Comment: Nice, thank you for the thorough explanation, that helped!